# Not assigning nil values to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-1.9, null

Is there a short hand or best practice for assigning things to a hash when they are nil in ruby? For example, my problem is that I am using another hash to build this and if something in it is nil, it assigns nil to that key, rather than just leaving it alone. I understand why this happens so my solution was:

```
hash1[:key] = hash2[:key] unless hash2[:key].nil?
```

Because I cannot have a value in the has where the key actually points to nil. (I would rather have an empty hash than one that has {:key => nil}, that can't happen)

My question would be is there a better way to do this? I don't want to do a delete_if at the end of the assignments.

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me.  If you gave the whole loop as an example, there would be several good ways to make it into one line, I am sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

a little bit shorter if you negate the "unless" statement

```
hash1[:key] = hash2[:key] if hash2[:key]   # same as   if ! hash2[:key].nil?
```

you could also do the comparison in a && statement as suggested in other answers by Michael or Marc-Andre

It's really up to you, what you feel is most readable for you.  By design, there are always multiple ways in Ruby to solve a problem.

You could also modify the hash2 :

```
hash1 = hash2.reject{|k,v| v.nil?}

hash2.reject!{|k,v| v.nil?}   # even shorter, if in-place editing of hash2
```

this would remove key/value pairs :key => nil from hash2 (in place, if you use reject! )

Comment: > false.nil?
 => false

Comment: Beware, `reject!` returns nil if no changes were made.

Answer (score 5):

I like this the best, loop and conditional overriding all in one line!

```
h1 = {:foo => 'foo', :bar => 'bar'}
h2 = {:foo => 'oof', :bar => nil}

h1.merge!(h2) { |key, old_val, new_val| new_val.nil? ? old_val : new_val }

#=> {:foo => 'oof', :bar => 'bar'}
```

This will replace every value in h1 with the value of h2 where the keys are the same and the h2 value is not nil.

Comment: yes and no :/   If you have a nil value in h2 and h1 is empty, it will set the value in h1 to nil.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
hash2.each_pair do |key, value|
  next if value.nil?
  hash1[key] = value
end
```

If you are doing just a single assignment, this could shave a few characters:

```
hash2[:key] && hash1[:key] = hash2[:key]
```

My first example could also be shaved a bit further:

```
hash2.each_pair{ |k,v| v && hash1[k] = v }
```

I think the first is the easiest to read/understand. Also, examples 2 and 3 will skip anything that evaluates false (`nil` or `false`). This final example is one line and won't skip `false` values:

```
hash2.each_pair{ |k,v| v.nil? || hash1[k] = v }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if that's really any better, but

```
hash2[:key] && hash[:key] = hash2[:key]
```

could work. Note that this would behave the same way for `false` and `nil`, if that's not what you want

```
!hash2[:key].nil? && hash[:key] = hash2[:key]
```

would be better. All of this assuming that `:key` would be an arbitrary value that you may not have control over.

Comment: +1 that's correct. But basically does the same as the Red's solution

Comment: Of course it does the same. The way I understood the question, he wasn't happy with the style of the code, not the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best practice is to copy the `nil` value over to the hash. If one passes an option `:foo => nil`, it can mean something and should override a default `:foo` of `42`, for example. This also makes it easier to have options which should default to `true`, although one should use `fetch` in those cases:

```
opt = hash.fetch(:do_cool_treatment, true) # => will be true if key is not present
```

There are many ways to copy over values, including `nil` or `false`.

For a single key, you can use `has_key?` instead of the lookup:

```
hash1[:key] = hash2[:key] if hash2.has_key? :key
```

For all (or many) keys, use `merge!`:

```
hash1.merge!(hash2)
```

If you only want to do this for a couple of keys of `hash2`, you can slice it:

```
hash1.merge!(hash2.slice(:key, ...))
```

Comment: If `hash2` has keys with `nil` values, `merge!` will not work as `hash1` would have those same keys and their `nil` values... exactly what the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: the merge has the disadvantage that it would copy a :key => nil key/value pair to hash1 if it exists in hash2.  I think the OP didn't want that.

Comment: @Tilo: Edited to reflect my opinion that it's best to copy `nil` values.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if the merge doesn't work because you want more control:

```
hash1[:key] = hash2.fetch(:key, hash1[:key])
```

This will set hash1's :key to be hash2, unless it doesn't exist. In that case, it will use the default value (2nd argument to fetch), which is hash1's key

Comment: this wouldn't work if :key is not already in hash1 (right hand side)

Comment: @RickR You're right... doh! ... would need to fetch on the right side too: `hash1[:key] = hash2.fetch(:key, hash1.fetch(:key, nil))` ... and that just looks a little ugly

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your initializers **hash.rb**

```
class Hash
  def set_safe(key,val)
    if val && key
      self[key] = val
    end
  end
end
```

use

```
hash = {}
hash.set_safe 'key', value_or_nil
```